# How to make a navigation buttons animate to certain spots on interior pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, nav

So a client of mine is asking, without Flash, if I can build a homepage that has the navigation load in a certain spot but then if I click on one of the nav buttons, the whole nav, animates to different spots on the interior pages, is this possible without flash? With **jquery**? And **css3**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery has an `animate()` function that may interest you.

Take a look at the examples here: http://api.jquery.com/animate/

CSS3 also has some animation functionality http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_animations.asp, but the compatability is not supported in IE or Opera,

Comment: Ok so I was looking at this code but they all involve a button, how do I make a normal <a href> link make the animate instead of the button

Comment: actually a read a little farther down and saw I can do $( "a" ).click(function(){.....

Comment: Yeah, the `.click()` is what you're looking for initially. Inside that `.click()` you can use `this` to refer to the object click and animate it or another object entirely. jQuery provides a LOT of useful functions for this type of activity. Apologies for it taking me so long to get back to you and I hope it's working for you =).

Answer (score 0):

You might also look at the jQuery [scrollTo](http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/) plugin.